# How to make delphi VCL application run from the command line

Tags: batch-file, delphi, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I've got a VCL application in Delphi 10.2.
User should choose a few settings and then press the "Run" button.

Now I want this app to run automatically once a day (using Task Scheduler in Windows) with the settings that the user set up already in the app. So I need a solution to run the "Run" button routine from the command line.

How can I make this app not to open the main form, but to run behind the scenes, using the chosen settings?

As far as I understand, I'm supposed to make another unit that would run some scripts from the main VCL App, would get the settings and would pass them as parameters to a function which will call the "Run" button routine.
But here I cannot figure out how can I run this unit instead of the main form when Task Scheduler is running the app and not the user.

Or maybe there is a different solution?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: split the program into 2 programs, a GUI program for changing the settings, and a command line program the uses these settings (settings stored in ini/json/xml/registry/whatever). The cmmand line version can then be used in task scheduler

Comment: Do it the other way around: concentrate on your console application and later add a GUI version which just runs the console version. Handling both in one program is possible, but not for beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a command-line parameter for the exe and run the application accordingly.

To read the command line parameter use the function `ParamStr` (when you only use one command line parameter, you can use `ParamStr(1)` to read the first and only parameter).
When you need to have more command line parameters, then use `ParamCount` to iterate through all the available parameters.

Depending on the way you want to run your ‘Run’ code and have your config form shown, you can edit the projects `.dpr` file to show/create the main form when you run the app in ‘config’ mode and in the other case execute the ‘run’ code.

```
program MyProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  ConfigFormUnit in 'ConfigFormUnit.pas' {ConfigForm},
  RunCodeUnit in 'RunCodeUnit.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;

  if ParamStr(1) = 'run' then
    ExecuteRunCode
  else begin
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TConfigForm, ConfigForm);
  end;

  Application.Run;
end.
```

The routine `ExecuteRunCode` is a public routine in one of the units, which contains the code you want to run in 'Run' mode. (in the example the unit `RunCodeUnit.pas`).

```
unit RunCodeUnit;

interface

  procedure ExecuteRunCode;

implementation

procedure ExecuteRunCode;
begin
  // Code to run
end;

end.
```

Of course, you can create two separate programs, each having its own specific code, but this way you can use a single application if you want/need.

Comment: I guess it is a horses for courses thing. As stated, the OP never wants the user to run the operational program outside the scheduler, when splitting it into 2 is the answer, but more common is, IMHO the operational part will need to be run scheduled or ad hoc, in which case a single program is the better answer.

Comment: Can you explain why `Application.` is needed for both?

Comment: @Dsm yes, normally I would split the code into two programs too and use a shared unit for accessing the configuration. But based on the question it seems a single application is wanted.

Comment: @AmigoJack the use of the `Application` object depends on what to OP wants to do when the app is in ‘run’ mode. If he wants for example to show a Form with a progress bar, then he can use `Application.CreateForm` to create that form. I just changed the default code to demonstrate how he can switch between ‘config’ and ‘run’ mode using a command line parameter.

Comment: @LenaGavrilov you’re welcome. When you really like this answer, please mark it as ‘the answer’ to your question...

Comment: @R.Hoek I would have reversed the parameter check logic so that if the parameter is empty application GUI is shown and if first parameter is `-s` (s for silent) application executes silently with last saved settings. This way double clicking on application executable will always show application GUI and thus allow user to change its settings. In your example user needs to pass "config" as parameter in order to open the application GUI which is not intuitive. But setting a Task which passes additional parameters to application is.

Comment: @SilverWarior that might be a better choice, as the user would get some feedback. I’d then use something like `run` as param, but that’s a matter of taste 

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to create a command line only version of your application. This is named "`console mode`" application in Delphi terminology (File / new / console application).

You can access command line parameters using `ParamStr` and `ParamCount`.

If you need both command line and GUI application, put all not GUI code into one unit, encapsulating it in a class or as standard function. The you can use that unit from the GUI application and from the console mode application.

By the way, it is a good design to always separate user interface from business code. You have a good example of that need here: you either use the code from a GUI application or from a command line application and you could as well use it from a service application or inside a DLL.